# Implementation of shared state among cucumber steps in java

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I have two-page objects called `OrderSelection` and `OrderDetails`. In addition, I have `SharedState` class and `OrderSelectionStepDef` and `OrderDetailsStepDef`. I declared two variables for `OrderSelection` and `OrderDetails` in `SharedState`. However, they are not initialized in the constructor of `SharedState`. 
    In `OrderSelectionStepDef` and `OrderDetailsStepDef` classes, I declared their constructors and pass `SharedState` object.

```
public OrderSelectionStepDef(SharedState sharedState) {
  this.sharedState = sharedState;
}    
public OrderDetailsStepDef(SharedState sharedState) {
  this.sharedState = sharedState;
}
```

When I call `sharedState.orderDetails` within `OrderDetailsStepDef` or `OrderSelectionStepDef` a `NullPointerException` was thrown.

Then, I initialized `OrderSelection` and `OrderDetails` class objects in `SharedState` constructor. Then the issue was solved. But is this implementation ok with cucumber pico container concept?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Step 1. OrderSelectionStepDef & OrderDetailsStepDef would look like below*** (please change name as per your implementation)

```
/**
 * Step Definition implementation class for Cucumber Steps defined in Feature file
 */

public class HomePageSteps extends BaseSteps {

    TestContext testContext;

    public HomePageSteps(TestContext context) {
        testContext = context;
    }

    @When("^User is on Brand Home Page (.+)$")
    public void user_is_on_Brand_Home_Page(String siteName) throws InterruptedException {
        homePage = new HomePage().launchBrandSite(siteName);
        testContext.scenarioContext.setContext(Context.HOMEPAGE, homePage);
    }

    @Then("^Clicking on Sign In link shall take user to Sign In Page$")
    public void clicking_on_Sign_In_link_shall_take_user_to_Sign_In_Page() {
        homePage = (HomePage) testContext.scenarioContext.getContext(Context.HOMEPAGE);
        signInPage = homePage.ecommSignInPageNavigation();
        testContext.scenarioContext.setContext(Context.SIGNINPAGE, signInPage);
    }
```

***For your reference***

```
public class BaseSteps {

    protected HomePage homePage;
    protected PLPPage plpPage;
    protected PDPPage pdpPage;
    protected ShoppingBagPage shoppingBagPage;
    protected ShippingPage shippingPage;

More implementation goes here.....  

}
```

***Step 2. Please add below 2 Classes under your framework -***

*First, Java file name - **ScenarioContext.java***

```
public class ScenarioContext {

    private  Map<String, Object> scenarioContext;

    public ScenarioContext(){
        scenarioContext = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    public void setContext(Context key, Object value) {
        scenarioContext.put(key.toString(), value);
    }

    public Object getContext(Context key){
        return scenarioContext.get(key.toString());
    }

    public Boolean isContains(Context key){
        return scenarioContext.containsKey(key.toString());
    }
}
```

*Second, Java file name - **TestContext.java***

```
public class TestContext {

    public ScenarioContext scenarioContext;

    public TestContext(){
        scenarioContext = new ScenarioContext();
    }

    public ScenarioContext getScenarioContext() {
        return scenarioContext;
    }
}
```

***Step 3. POM Dependency*** - picocontainer shall be as per your cucumber version

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hope this helps.